# I am trying to set cookie from backend but it is not showing and not getting console.log

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to set cookie called JWT from backend but it is not able to set and I am not getting cookie in browser too where I am going wrong?

**backend code for storing cookie**

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const findData = await Registeration.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  console.log(findData);
  if (findData === null || findData === {}) {
    res.status(404).json({message:"user not found",statusCode:res.statusCode});
  } else {
    if (findData.password === req.body.password) {
      const token = await findData.generateAuthToken();
      console.log(token);
      res.cookie("jwt", token, {
        path: "/",
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 30 * 100),
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
      });
      console.log("cookie : ",req.cookies.jwt)// getting undefined
      if (findData.isSeller === true) {
        res.status(200).json({message:"logged into as seller",statusCode:res.statusCode});
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({message:"welcome to customer page",statusCode:res.statusCode});
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).send("ircorrect password");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is cookie present in the dev tools in the application tab?

Comment: yess it showing in network tab like set-cookie but not in cookie in application tab

Comment: You can't read httponly cookie using javascript, that's the point

Comment: any solution? i need help

Comment: Remove `httpOnly: true`